# Google Charts Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, charts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
    <?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Freqency'],
          ['<?php echo $row['name']?>', 
           '<?php echo $row['gender']?>', 
           '<?php echo $row['age']?>', 
           '<?php echo $row['freq']?>']
        ]);
    <?php  ?>
    }

...

</script>
```

This works and a chart appears , but show me only the last entry that was in database table, and there is 4 entrys.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Freqency'],
          <?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
          ['<?php echo $row['name']?>' , '<?php echo $row['gender']?>', <?php echo $row['age']?>, <?php echo $row['freq']?>],
          <?php } ?>
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're building the data structure wrong. If you did a view source of the generated page, you'd see

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(...);
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(...);
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(...);
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(...);
```

where each new row overwrites/destroys the previous row. Move the `var data` line OUTSIDE of your fetch loop:

```
var data = google.visualiation.arrayToDataTable([
['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Freqency'],
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```

this probably won't work, but should give you the general idea. Note the use of json_encode(). You're not using it in your code, and if a person's name (say) contains a `'`, you'll introduce a javascript syntax error and kill the entire script. using json_encode() guarantees that you're converting the php data into syntactically correct javascript.

Comment: You probably right! I need to study a bit about this json_encode!

Comment: Could you provide me some easy stuff about json ?